# trying to configure geojson file for a particular map

Tags: d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to configure a map that shows a view of the US with some of the buttom of Canada and some of the top of Mexico.  I did a basic capture of this in www.geojson.io:

http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/b2f65ddc2a28013b0c9c7ecab5d7427f&map=4/39.37/-97.16

How can I display this in a browser map using d3.js? I'm able to display a browser map of the world using world-110m.json which seems to be a commonly used geojson file:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4090846/raw/d534aba169207548a8a3d670c9c2cc719ff05c47/world-110m.json

Here's the d3 code I'm using to display the geojson as a browser map:

```
d3.json("json/world-110m.json", function (error, topology) {
    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    g.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
            .geometries)
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
});
```

World-110m.json seems to have a lot of additional info I don't need because I just need to display a flat map of the area captured in my geojson.io map above. Do I need to build out my geojson, update my d3 code or both?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `geojson.io` is doing but the geojson it's returning (two identical polygons) doesn't seem to correlate to anything resembling your selection.

For what it is worth, here's the "map" from that `geojson`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var geoJson = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [-129.0234375,
                23.160563309048314
              ],
              [-129.0234375,
                52.53627304145948
              ],
              [-65.302734375,
                52.53627304145948
              ],
              [-65.302734375,
                23.160563309048314
              ],
              [-129.0234375,
                23.160563309048314
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Polygon",
          "coordinates": [
            [
              [-129.0234375,
                23.160563309048314
              ],
              [-129.0234375,
                52.53627304145948
              ],
              [-65.302734375,
                52.53627304145948
              ],
              [-65.302734375,
                23.160563309048314
              ],
              [-129.0234375,
                23.160563309048314
              ]
            ]
          ]
        }
      }]
    };


    var width = 960,
      height = 600;


    var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
      .scale(500)
      .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);


    var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);


    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(geoJson.features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: right I think it added a duplicate polygon when the file was reopened.  however, I did remove the duplicate polygon before attempting to run it in my local d3 app.  I also converted the geojson file to topojson before running in my local d3 app. however, topojson.v0.min.js: returns "Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" for some reason

Comment: I fixed the immediate error by removing the "countries" property reference in my d3 b/c the json file didn't have a countries object.  I guess what I'm looking for is a basic topojson file that will work for my scenario.  I can adjust implementation details as needed.